# How to alter the position of a legend in a bar plot in R?

Tags: r, bar-chart, legend

I generated a barplot in R but the legend is covering almost all of the plot. How can I adjust it to a different position? For example besides/outside of the plot?

This is my code:

```
compare <- table(cats$color, cats$coat)
bar2 <- barplot(compare, legend = rownames(compare), main = 'Comparing coat design to color')
bar2
```

Answer (score 0):

We can't give you the exact settings since you haven't provided an example of your data, but the general advice is as follows:

If you have a large legend, you can place it in the margins of the plot rather than over the plot. To do that, adjust `mar` so that there is room for it, and set `xpd = TRUE`.  Here's an example with `mtcars`:

```
df <- head(mtcars, 14)
par(mar = c(5.1, 4.1, 4.1, 9.1), xpd = TRUE)
barplot(df$mpg)
legend("topright", inset = c(-0.5, -0.3), rownames(df))
```

[image]

Comment: Here it is how the data set looks like: 

"breed","sex","spay.neuter","coat","color"
"domestic shorthair","Male","No","tabby","orange"
"domestic shorthair","Female","No","tabby","blue"
"domestic shorthair","Female","Yes","","white"
"domestic mediumhair","Female","Yes","","black"
"domestic shorthair","Male","No","","black"
"domestic shorthair","Female","Yes","tabby","brown"
"domestic shorthair","Female","Yes","tabby","brown"